# Search for a Range of Values in a Sorted CSV File Using Python

Tags: python, csv, search

I have a large CSV file (500,000+ rows, with 4 columns) that is sorted according to the first column. From a given number, I need to find all values corresponding to the first column within a +- range. For instance, given 10+-.05, I would need to find all values between 9.95 and 10.05 in the first column, and then return all rows within that range. Since the file is already sorted by the first column, I'm thinking this should be fairly easy, but I can't figure out a way to quickly search for a given range and return every row within that range at once.

Thanks for any help

Comment: If the data is a) not in memory and b) in a file with *variable line sizes*, your only option is to scan through the file until you reach the range.

Comment: If the data is a) sorted and b) you know the number of lines in the file, you can use a binary search to efficiently locate the min and max values of the range.

Comment: The file doesn't have variable line sizes; each is 4 columns with a  64 bit floating point number in each field.

Comment: @JoelCornett are you saying you'd read all 500k lines into memory first and then run binary search?

Comment: @JoelCornett are you saying you'd read all 500k lines into memory first and then run binary search?

Comment: Are the string representations of the 64 bit floating point numbers all the same width?  If yes then you can calculate the width of each row and use use `your_file.seek(some_index * row_width)` to find specific records.  This means you would not have to read the whole file to do a binary search.  However, it seems your file is not so large that it would not fit in memory, so why bother?  Are you sure this is not a premature optimization?

Comment: Well, unfortunately they are not all the same width by a very small margin, so I guess that can't work. Is there a native way to run a binary search on the file?

Comment: @A4Treok:  It seems to me you can approximate a binary search by reading more characters than can be in a single row, find a newline, and then parse the following row.  But this will take some effort to code.  Again, are you sure this is not a premature optimization?

Comment: Sorry, just saw the end of your comment. It's not extremely large to the point where I need it to be heavily optimized, but the file it was derived from was 2.4 GB, so it definitely took a lot to get it to where it is now. I was just wondering if there was a way of doing it in general, in case the file got larger.

Comment: It would seem that a CSV file is probably not the best format for your use case. With a dataset that large, you might be better off with a database which implements various optimizations for lookups.